# Is it possible to either abort or interrupt and later continue a lvconvert -m1 operation?

Tags: linux, lvm

I have run the command

```
lvconvert -m1 rootvg/newroot /dev/sdb
```

to convert a linear logical volume to a mirrored one. The operation has not yet finished; I interrupted the command with ctrl-c at around 10% mark, but the operation seems to be running in the background anyway.

Is it possible to either

1) Abort the lvconvert operation and revert to the state before it? (This would be my preferred option)

2) To safely interrupt the operation and resume it later?

Comment: Why do you want to stop it?

Comment: Well, one reason would be to restart it with -t raid1 which after Googling probably would be a good idea. Another possible reason could be that it takes surprisingly long and won't finish in the time I'm willing to give it (estimated 100 hours for a 1 TB volume seems a lot to me).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you're most certainly done with the whole ordeal, for future reference:

```
lvconvert -m0 rootvg/newroot
```

will do the job.